# Add_Trace issue in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

How can I increase the length of the green (lcl) and red line (lsl) so that they extend to the end of the plot (rather than stopping halfway) in the `add_trace` function?
[image]

Here is my code for my graph:

```
      output$p <- renderPlotly({
plot1 %>%

                add_trace(y = lcl(),type = "scatter", mode = "lines", line = list(color = 'lightgreen', width = 2, dash = 'solid'), inherit = FALSE, name = paste("LCL =", lcl()[1])) %>%
     
                add_trace(y = lsl(),type = "scatter", mode = "lines", line = list(color = 'red', width = 2, dash = 'solid'), inherit = FALSE, name = paste("LSL =", lsl()[1])) %>%
              %>%
                layout(
                    title = paste(" cell culture", input$select),
                    yaxis = list(  showline = TRUE,
                                   mirror = "ticks",
                                   linecolor = toRGB("grey"),
                                   linewidth = 1.85
                    ),
                    xaxis = list(  showline = TRUE,
                                   mirror = "ticks",
                                   linecolor = toRGB("grey"),
                                   linewidth = 1.85,
                                   tickangle=70))
        })
```

edit: i got rid of the code for the actual plot (the scatter plot) for simplicity, that graph is fine and does not need any tweaking.

Comment: It seems you're using my answer below in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68687940/9098350). Be sure to accept and upvote answers you find helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `add_trace` for creating horiontal lines that span the entire graph I would add horizontal lines as a shapes to the layout:

```
layout(shapes = list(
  list(
    type = "line",
    x0 = 0,
    x1 = 1,
    xref = "paper",
    y0 = 75,
    y1 = 75,
    line = list(color = 'lightgreen', width = 2)
  ),
  list(
    type = "line",
    x0 = 0,
    x1 = 1,
    xref = "paper",
    y0 = 100,
    y1 = 100,
    line = list(color = 'red', width = 2)
  )
))
```

`xref = "paper"` is used so the line spans the entire graph.

> Positioning in paper coordinates is not done in absolute pixel terms, but rather in terms relative to a coordinate system defined with an origin (0,0) at (layout.margin.l, layout.margin.b) and a point (1,1) at (layout.width-layout.margin.r, layout.height-layout.margin.t)...

https://plotly.com/python/figure-structure/#positioning-with-paper-container-coordinates-or-axis-domain-coordinates

Change the `y` values according to your requirements.